# How to run 2 javascript codes in order to get correct result

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC project. I get user's current location's city and put it on the top right corner on webpage, This is the first javascript code that runs. The second javascript code runs to get that city's weather condition. But by the time the js that runs to get the weather, city name is not set by the first js.

So, I need to make sure that before running the second js, the first js is completes. How can I do that?

here are my js codes.

First on is jquery code

```
<script>
    function GetUsersInfo()
    {
        $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            $("#cityName").html(''+response.city);
            if ($("#cityName").html === "")
            {
                $("#cityName").html("İstanbul");
            }
        }, "jsonp");
    }
    GetUsersInfo();
</script>
```

Second code is angular js

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("ZenHaberApp", []);
app.controller("WeatherController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var $city = document.getElementById("cityName").innerHTML
    alert($city)
    $http.get('http://localhost:62747/api/getweatherbycityname/' + $city).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.weathers = data.condition_temp;
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert(status);
      });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options :

1. use events, after loading the data you could dispatch a global event and listen to that anywhere else. the `observer` pattern is implemented in jQuery so since you already using jQuery this is easy.  ( $.on and $.trigger )
2. since you are using jsonp, you could use jsonp callback. 
   further explanation in Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Callback_name_manipulation_and_reflected_file_download_attack
3. obviously using intervals (setInterval and check the value element) although this is not a good approach

In my opinion option 1 is the best approach.

I've taken into account that the codes are totally separated and you don't want to couple angular to the first part .

Answer (score 1):

In your situation I would make the two requests on the same flow, and use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to manage them.

With async you could use the [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#waterfall) method to do this:

```
var async = require('async');

var app = angular.module("ZenHaberApp", []);
app.controller("WeatherController", function ($scope, $http) {

    async.waterfall([
      function (callback) {
        // Make the request to get the city, if jsonp needed check $http.jsop method (remember to use the $sce module to trust the source)
        // Assign the city to a $scope variable, which with angular simple add {{city}} to show to the user
        // Async takes callbacks with two params (error, result) so you could do callback(err, city)
      },
      function (city, callback) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:62747/api/getweatherbycityname/' + city).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            callback(null, data)
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        callback(true);
        });
      }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
        // Handle error 
      } else {
        $scope.weathers = data.condition_temp;
      }
    });    
});
```

Comment: @Derek Actually async is designed to end callback hell

Comment: Promises are designed to end the callback hell. The code example you posted still has callbacks, thus still being a callback hell. Promises have no callbacks.

Comment: @Derek Well, from what I have read just because it has callbacks it doesn't mean is a callback hell situation. 'Callback hell' is when you get very deep into several callback calls waiting for asynchronous responses, for example [this post](https://www.terlici.com/2015/10/28/solving-node-callback-hell-asyncjs.html) talks about what I've mentioned async can do for those types of calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 2, there is something call Lifecycle Hooks

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

(I do not know if is an Angular first version feature to)

In there you can define scrips along the lifecycle of the view or component, and then you can set that scrips in different lifecycle hooks.

I hope that helps.